# Why is my rendering not using CUDA even though I have selected it and saved it in my preferences

Tags: blender

I am using Blender 2.82.
I have GTX970M on my machine.
I have selected CUDA in my preferences and yes it shows my GPU 970M. And its also saved.
But still when I render it's using my CPU instead of GPU.
When I go back to the preferences I can see that is saved but its simply ignoring the option during rendering.

[image]

Can someone help me what mistake am I doing?

I have so far tried the following.

1. Restarted blender after saving the preference.
2. Updating NVIDIA drivers and restarting my machine

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found out the issue.
I had to set the GPU compute in rendering settings as well.
[image]